# Могут ли два Data Mapper'а работать с одной таблицей?

Tags: база-данных, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблоны

Суть такова. У меня есть таблица `files`, вот примерная строчка из нее:

```
id | name | album | size | path | user
1  | 1.jpg| photo | 4324 | x/y/z| id23123
```

У меня есть FilesMapper, который вычленяет целые строки из этой таблицы и создает сущности, именуемые как File. Сейчас мне понадобилось вычленить только конкретную информацию из таблицы, а точнее список альбомов, которые принадлежат определенному юзверю. Хочу создать сущность Album и AlbumMapper, который будет тягать инфу из этой таблицы. Идеалогически верно ли это и соответствует шаблону? Или лучше всего создать отдельную таблицу, где альбом будет первичным ключом?

Смущает то, что таблица вроде как составлена с учетом 3 нормальных форм и дробить ее на более мелкие сущности смысла не вижу.

Что подскажете?

Comment: 3-НФ уже нарушена, так как есть зависимость между альбомом и пользователем. А следовательно в БД могут быть ошибки такого вида, что два файла входят в один альбом но при этом пользователи разные. Что то мне подсказывает, что таблиц должно быть 3: пользователи, альбомы, которые ссылаются на пользователей и файлы, которые в альбомы входят (но у них нет прямой ссылки на пользователя)

Comment: @Mike _два файла входят в один альбом но при этом пользователи разные_
А разве это ошибка? Я, например, делаю выборку, по одному пользователю у которого в одном альбоме такие-то файлы. Точно такие же файлы в точно таком же альбоме другого пользователя запрос не затрагивает)

Comment: @Mike насчет разграничения полей, ты интересную схему предложил,  я в самом начале думал так спроектировать, но решил, что так делать - плодить лишние сущности. А вот сейчас напоролся на такое)